# How to filter child collections Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api

WEB API

Model::

```
public class Empresa
{
    [Key]
    public string CDEmpresa { get; set; }

    public string NomeFantasia { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public string Nome{ get; set; }

    public List<EmpresaRamoAtividade> EmpresaRamoAtividade { get; set; }
}

public class EmpresaRamoAtividade
{
    [Key]
    public int CTRamoAtividade { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public string CDEmpresa { get; set; }

    public List<RamoAtividade> RamoAtividade { get; set; }
}


public class RamoAtividade
{
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    [Key]
    public int CTRamoAtividadeTraducao { get; set; }

    public int CTRamoAtividade { get; set; }

    public string Atividade { get; set; }

    public int Idioma { get; set; }
}
```

Controller::

Working ok:::

```
{
    return db.Empresas
    .Where(a => a.Associado.IsAssociado)
    .Include(empresaRamo => empresaRamo.EmpresaRamoAtividade)
    .Include(ramo => ramo.EmpresaRamoAtividade.Select(atividade =>     atividade.RamoAtividade));
}
```

Not working, I have to filter by "idioma" (language):::

```
{
    return db.Empresas
    .Where(a => a.Associado.IsAssociado)
    .Include(empresaRamo => empresaRamo.EmpresaRamoAtividade)
    .Include(ramo => ramo.EmpresaRamoAtividade.Select(atividade => atividade.RamoAtividade.Where(idioma => idioma.Idioma == 1)));
}
```

Error:

> The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property
>   defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation
>   properties and the Select operator for collection navigation
>   properties. Parameter name: path

Can't I filter 3 level collection child?
Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

You cannot filter using Include methods. It only supports select.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Plus (EF+)](http://entityframework-plus.net/)

**EF+ Query IncludeFilter** allow you to easily filter related entities:

```
{
    return db.Empresas
    .Where(a => a.Associado.IsAssociado)
    .IncludeFilter(empresaRamo => empresaRamo.EmpresaRamoAtividade)
    .IncludeFilter(ramo => ramo.EmpresaRamoAtividade.Select(atividade => atividade.RamoAtividade.Where(idioma => idioma.Idioma == 1)));
}
```

You can find the documentation [here](http://entityframework-plus.net/query-include-filter)